# Sitecore SelectItems on Inherited Template

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to bind a asp:dropdownlist to a some sitecore items based on a query. With the query I want to return items that inherhit the template 'Site Root'.

When I use:

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("/sitecore/content/*[@@templatename='Site Root']");
```

It only returns items that have the template of 'Site Root', not the templates that inherit this template.

How do I get a query to return items that inherit this template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't query on an inherited template

Comment: Ok, will just alter my query to include all the templates that are inheriting from that template.

Comment: That's certainly an option, but the more checks you add into your query, the slower it _could possibly_ run. You should also consider doing a more generic query with the Sitecore API code then using LINQ to filter the result items by `TemplateName`

Comment: Wrong. You can... see the answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a query that returns all templates inheriting a specific template. But be careful as it will not perform very well.

```
/sitecore/templates//*[contains(@__Base template, '<MY TEMPLATE ID>')]
```

If performance matters, you'd probably be better off using Sitecore ContentSearch to query the templates. There is a `__template` computed field for that which needs to be activated first though. See [Sitecore-7-Enable-Default-Computed-Index-Fields](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-7-enable-default-computed-index-fields) for details.

Comment: thanks for that! when you can narrow down the location of your queried templates it's performing quite well actually ;-)